# Jquery Full Calendar Customize Scroll Bar

Tags: fullcalendar, fullcalendar-scheduler

I am trying to modify jquery full calendar scroll bar color, width and shape.  Tried to modify css settings of .fc-scroller but didn't work. 
Is it possible ?

Comment: You're going to have to give us your code so that we can see what you're talking about.

Comment: What exactly did you try? And in which browsers did you test? Some browsers have more support for scrollbar customisation than others. Without seeing your code and knowing other info such as I mentioned we cannot really help you solve your problem. Please edit your question appropriately, thankyou

Answer (score 3):

You can use this customization, this customization is for the resource timeline plugin, and the before /* SCROLLBAR - START - */ I have put one more horizontal scrollbar to the top. You don't have to use it.

```
 .fc-scroller { 
 margin-bottom: 0px !important;
}




/* SCROLLBAR - START - */

/* width */
.fc-scroller::-webkit-scrollbar {
     width: 15px;
 }

 /* Track */
.fc-scroller::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
     box-shadow: inset 0 0 5px grey; 
     border-radius: 0px;
 }



/* Handle */
.fc-scroller::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
     background: linear-gradient(#ffffff, #103E62);; 
 }



/* Handle on hover */
.fc-scroller::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:hover {
     background: #103E62; 
 }




/* Firefox Integration */

.fc-scroller{
     scrollbar-color: #103E62 #fff;
 }
 
 /* SCROLLBAR - END - */
```